# add harddisk to Ubuntu and mount it to /var/www/

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have installed an Ubuntu server on a VMWare workstation with a space of 20GB storage as seen below:

[image]

After the installation I've attached another 40GB worth storage to the existing Ubuntu server installation (seen below):

[image: http://img.ie/opm20.png]

Now I want to add this 40GB to my `/` (root) directory or to `/var/` directory but my `df -h` result shows;

```
root@Userver:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        18G  900M   16G   6% /
udev            990M  4.0K  990M   1% /dev
tmpfs           400M  308K  399M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            999M     0  999M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
root@Userver:~#
```

What should I do now? Further, I have only ssh access to the server.

some one told me to do :

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb -I
```

and when i do this command :

```
root@Userver:~# ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5
```

if you look carefully you , you don't see 
"sdb" or "sdb1"

Next , i'm restart Ubuntu-server and after restart there was a "sdb" on "/dev/" 
like this :

```
root@Userver:~# ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb
```

now when i do this command :

```
root@Userver:~# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb -I
mkfs.ext4: option requires an argument -- 'I'
Usage: mkfs.ext4 [-c|-l filename] [-b block-size] [-C cluster-size]
        [-i bytes-per-inode] [-I inode-size] [-J journal-options]
        [-G flex-group-size] [-N number-of-inodes]
        [-m reserved-blocks-percentage] [-o creator-os]
        [-g blocks-per-group] [-L volume-label] [-M last-mounted-directory]
        [-O feature[,...]] [-r fs-revision] [-E extended-option[,...]]
        [-t fs-type] [-T usage-type ] [-U UUID] [-jnqvDFKSV] device [blocks-count]
```

,,,,,,,,,

please help me, i want to add the 40G hard to ubuntu 12.04,
and mount it to "/var/www/"  but i cant do that

i use some how to's and i get this error's :

```
root@Userver:~# mount /dev/sdb1 /var/www/
mount: mount point /var/www/ does not exist
```

i dont know what should i do

Comment: `mount: mount point /var/www/ does not exist` means the directory does not exist. From a terminal, you need to `sudo mkdir /var/www`.

Comment: Hints/tips: there is a command called "parted" (the command line backend for gParted) that should be able to add and resize your partitions ( https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/resize.html ) (never used it myself ;-) )

Comment: how to i can , append 40G to all "/" directory ? , it's mean my "/" will be 20G +40G = 60 ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a disk was the first thing to do indeed.

Next, you have to partition your disk. You need at least one partition in it :

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
```

You have to choose option `n` then `p` (for a primary partition), a number for the partition (let's take 1 to start).
The you are prompted to enter the first sector (should be 0) and then the last one (the default is proposing you to create a partition on the whole disk).
If you are prompted to enter a partition type, choose `83`, the Linux partition type.

Once this is done, exit by pressing `w`.

Then you can do :

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
```

This will create a Ext4 filesystem on the newly created partition. If there is error saying unknown device, you may need to reboot the VM.

Then, be sure you have the `/var/www` directory and add the following into `/etc/fstab`.

```
/dev/sdb1      /var/www    ext4     errors=remount-ro,relatime      0       2
```

This will allow the system to mount automatically the newly create filesystem under `/var/www`.

Once you've written this into the **fstab**, you can manually mount the filesystem without rebooting as simply as typing `sudo mount /var/www`.